# How can I recover deleted photos from memory card?

Tags: data-recovery, photos, file-recovery, memory-card

A few days back I found that the photos I have saved in my memory card have been lost. I don’t know what is the reason behind the deletion of photos but I just want them back.

How can I restore my lost photos?

Comment: Depending on your OS, there are a number of data recovery programs available, some of them freeware. What results did you get from a search?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, some/all data CAN be recovered, provided that the disk space hasn't been overwritten with some new data.

[Here](https://www.howtogeek.com/125521/htg-explains-why-deleted-files-can-be-recovered-and-how-you-can-prevent-it/)'s a good explaination of what happens in Windows OS when you delete a file:

*When you delete a file, Windows removes the pointer and marks the sectors containing the file’s data as available. From the file system’s point of view, the file is no longer present on your hard drive and the sectors containing its data are considered free space.
However, until Windows actually writes new data over the sectors containing the contents of the file, the file is still recoverable. A file recovery program can scan a hard drive for these deleted files and restore them. If the file has been partially overwritten, the file recovery program can only recover part of the data.*

Since you said you haven't deleted the files yourself, we can't be sure if this is what's going on. But you can try to find the lost data with recovery programs. I think [Recuva](https://www.ccleaner.com/recuva) would be the best program to start with. If there's no luck, you can try other recovery programs as well, but I'd trust Recuva would find the lost files if they can be found.